# Помощь с setInterval и setTimeout. "Карусель"

Tags: javascript, setinterval

При загрузке страницы, интервал стартует как надо.
Я поставил кнопку для паузы интервала, но работает не так как надо.

При клике на кнопку происходит пауза, но только на определенный срок времени, а должна быть полная пауза пока не кликну на старт. В чем проблема?

При загрузке страницы,  интервал должен сразу стартовать. Я написал это, но не знаю грамотно ли.

Прошу код не менять, если нет большой необходимости. Если код поменяли, пожалуйста прокомментируйте, и если не сложно, то объясните где не грамотный  код.

Спасибо.

Использовать только на JS

```js
(function() {
  var elem, startInterval, removedElem, widthBlock,
    btn1 = document.getElementById('click1'),
    btn2 = document.getElementById('click2'),
    collectionBlocks = document.getElementById('collection_divs');


  function clearThisInterval() {
    if (thisElem.clientWidth == 0) {
      removedElem = collectionBlocks.removeChild(collectionBlocks.children[0]);
      collectionBlocks.appendChild(removedElem);
      thisElem.style.width = '150px';

      clearInterval(startInterval); //удаляем интервал
      // для следующего блока
    }
  }

  function minWidth() {
    thisElem = collectionBlocks.children[0];
    widthBlock = thisElem.clientWidth;
    // Уменьшаем ширину
    if (widthBlock != 0) {
      startInterval = setInterval(function() {
        thisElem.style.width = [widthBlock -= 2] + 'px';
      }, 30);
    }
    setTimeout(clearThisInterval, 2253); // 15 строка //удаляем интервал
  }

  // Запускаем интервал / строка 19
  btn2.onclick = function() {
    setInterval(minWidth, 3000);
  }

  //становить или пауза  интервала для уменьшение ширины  / 23 строка //  
  btn1.onclick = function() {
    clearInterval(startInterval);
  }

  //при загрузке стартует сам
  //setInterval(minWidth, 5000);
})();
```

```css
.div {
  width: 150px;
  height: 30px;
  background-color: red;
  float: left;
  margin-right: 2px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  margin-top: 10px;
}

button {
  width: 100px;
  height: 40px;
}
```

```html
<button id="click1">stop</button>
<button id="click2">start</button>

<div id="collection_divs">
  <div class="div">1</div>
  <div class="div">2</div>
  <div class="div">3</div>
  <div class="div">3</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если какой-то код, который запускает таймер, вызывается больше одного раза, он должен запоминать значение, возвращаемое `setInterval`, и вызывать `clearInterval` с этим значением перед очередным вызовом `setInterval`.

```
  function minWidth() {
    thisElem = collectionBlocks.children[0];
    widthBlock = thisElem.clientWidth;
    // Уменьшаем ширину
    if (widthBlock != 0) {
      clearInterval(startInterval); // !!!
      startInterval = setInterval(function() {
        thisElem.style.width = [widthBlock -= 2] + 'px';
      }, 30);
    }
    setTimeout(clearThisInterval, 2253); // 15 строка //удаляем интервал
  }

  var minWidthInterval;
  // Запускаем интервал / строка 19
  btn2.onclick = function() {
    clearInterval(minWidthInterval); // !!!
    minWidthInterval = setInterval(minWidth, 3000);
  }

  //становить или пауза  интервала для уменьшение ширины  / 23 строка //    
  btn1.onclick = function() {
    clearInterval(minWidthInterval); // !!!
    clearInterval(startInterval);
  }
```